# primeng dropdown showing value not label on select

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

Using 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown the editable version of dropdown with filter

I am seeing that choosing an option shows the value instead of the label when selected.

[image]

code

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12"><p-dropdown [options]="metaAttributesOptions[n]" [filter]="true" editable="editable" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" *ngIf="metaAttributesOptions[n]" formControlName="value"></p-dropdown>



this.metaAttributesOptions.push(x.options.map(v => {
                            return {
                                label: v.name,
                                value: v.value
                            }
                        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not having the `label` attribute which is expected by primeng Dropdown object's type **[SelectItem](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown)**

So you need to modify your json in format of the SelectItem by looping into entire object and creating a custom object of type SelectItem as below,

```
forEach(serviceData =>(data) {
let color: SelectItem = { 

      label : data.name,
      value : data.id
})
```

Comment: actualyl checked it and it wasn't a typo

Comment: It wan't' a typo the label was set properly

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: I am saying that the issue wasn't the SelectItem object

Comment: then wat was the issue?. you updated the code as I said

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you can't use

editable="editable"

Not sure why.

Comment: According to their documentation `editable` is a boolean value. It is expecting something like `[editable]="true"`.